# compileSdkVersion is not specified on expo run android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I am trying to run the command `expo run:android` but i am getting this error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

But in the file build.gradle is specified.
I had other errors so I tried to reinstall, I currently have Java 8 update 333 installed.
I tried command `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches` but it did not help
Where is problem please?

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../android"))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../dist"))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Comment: I'm also having this problem, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be a mis-configured ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Double check that the variable points to the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer. Once you reopen your project, go to `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files`. This worked for me.

It might help to `Reload All from Disk` too.